# iis7 .net webservice 404 error

Tags: iis-7, asp.net, web-services, handler-mappings

I have a webservice `/test/Service1.asmx` in the same folder as a page `/test/test.aspx`.

The page works fine but I get the message bellow for the services in the same location. I know the file is there and the url is correct, and I have added the script module and managed handler as well. If anyone knows what I'm missing here I'd appreciate it

> ### Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> ---
>
> The resource cannot be found. 
>   Description: HTTP 404. The resource
>   you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed,
>   had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please
>   review the following URL and make sure
>   that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /test/Service1.asmx
>
> ---
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET
>   Framework Version:2.0.50727.4200;
>   ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.4016

FAILED REQUEST LOG:
ModuleName ManagedPipelineHandler 
Notification 128 
HttpStatus 404 
HttpReason Not Found 
HttpSubStatus 0 
ErrorCode 0 
ConfigExceptionInfo
Notification EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER 
ErrorCode The operation completed successfully. (0x0)

Comment: Can you run Failed Request Tracing and see at what stage it's failing.

Comment: yeah guess that would be a good first step, thx

Comment: Can you also check IIS logfile and see the exact error and the status code. I am most interested in sc-status, sc-substatus and sc-win32-status

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue while doing some test migrations of our intranet applications from IIS6 to 7. I was able to solve the problem by modifying the following section of the Web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>
   <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
   <modules>
      <remove name="ScriptModule"/>
   </modules>
   <handlers>
      <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
      <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory"/>
      <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices"/>
      <remove name="ScriptResource"/>
   </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Change *validateIntegratedModeConfiguration* to **true**, and remove the *WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated* from the remove list.

Oddly enough, from memmory ASP.NET adds those lines specifically IIS7. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

did you install ASP.NET Role Service for IIS 7?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, but for a completely different issue. Make sure you compile your site before deploying it. I had some pages that were compiled and some pages that were not compiled.

It took me so long to figure out because when I tried viewing these pages on the application server (Windows Server 2008), it wouldn't let me view a non secure page (http protocol), because of Internet Explorer's security settings. I only had a binding for port 80 when testing on a browser on the server box. So I couldn't even see the aspx page that was compiled, let alone the aspx pages that were not compiled. A plain HTML page was visible on both boxes however, on the same site--that part was interesting. When I viewed the pages on another machine (running Windows 7) on that network, the compiled aspx page showed up fine because it was compiled. And the non-compiled pages did not.